# Edit a collection in iteration?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

***Preface***

I'm building an application that scrape some data from internet.
The data scraped need to be updated in real time, so I running an infinite loop
that check each time if the previously page source is changed or not.
All these data are stored inside an `ObservableCollection` like this:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Models.Event> _allMatches = new ObservableCollection<Models.Event>();

public ObservableCollection<Models.Event> AllMatches
{
    get { return _matches; }
}
```

This `ObservableCollection` is bound in a `ListView` as following:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding AllMatches}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchNation" />
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchLeague" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

the `CollectionViewSource` helps me to organize the data in the `ListView` with `GroupStyle`, in this case for `Nation -> League`.

***Problem start***

I'll try to create a simple example code for explain better the problem. So each data scraped matches by an event, so I've essentially a list of events in the `ObservableCollection`.

*Example code:*

```
string oldData = null;
List<Event> matchListAll = new List<Event>();

while(true)
{
      string data = new WebClient().DownloadString("websiteLink");
      
      if(data != oldData) //There is an update! Get the new content
      {
            //code for scrape the event
            
            foreach(var item in ItemScraped)
            {
                  Event @event = new Event(); //this will contain the details of event scraped
                  @event.Date = item.Date; //and so on...
                  
                  matchListAll.Add(@event); //Add the event to a list
            }
            
            //when the scraping iteration is over I put all of this event in the ObservableCollection
            AddAllListItem(matchListAll);
      }
}
```

now the code above is really simple, get the event from internet and put them into an object, that's it.
When the scraping is completed I call `AddAllListItem`, this method will valorize the `ObservableCollection` bound in the ListView.

The structure of this method is this:

```
private void AddAllListItem(List<Event> matches)
{
    var allCollection = VM.AllMatches; //Access to AllMatches through the Vm (VM contain the ViewModel instance)
    
    foreach (var @event in matches) //Iterate through the element scraped 
    {
        //Add the scraped element to ObservableCollection so I can see it.
        allCollection.Add(new Event 
        {
            MatchDate = @event.MatchDate,
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

This code have a serious problem. I think someone has already figured out what happens.

In particular meanwhile I add the item in the ObservableCollection the method `AddAllListItem` is
called again, and the matches item that I passed as parameter was changed. This will generate
an exception:

> Collection was modified. enumeration operation may not execute.

***How to solve this situation?***

I've read several question asked here with this problem and other suggest to use `.ToList` or `.ToArray`, but I've an ObservableCollection and meanwhile I show the element on screen I need also to update them.
I never encountered such a situation, and I hope someone help me to shed light on
the problem and to solve it, thanks.

Comment: This is one of these "pick your poison" situations - use locking, or use ToList/ToArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you.

```
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly object lockList = new object();

    public object LockList
    {
        get { return lockList; }
    } 

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var eh = CollectionChanged;
        if (eh != null)
        {
            Dispatcher dispatcher = (from NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in eh.GetInvocationList()
                                     let dpo = nh.Target as DispatcherObject
                                     where dpo != null
                                     select dpo.Dispatcher).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dispatcher != null && dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, (Action)(() => OnCollectionChanged(e)));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in eh.GetInvocationList())
                    nh.Invoke(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    new public void Remove(T item)
    {
        lock (lockList)
        {
            base.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    new public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (lockList)
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void AddByCheckExistence(T item)
    {
        lock (lockList)
        {
            if(!this.Contains(item))
            {
                base.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm I need to learn your code a bit, never used `IClonable`, hope in some explaination from you. Thanks.

Comment: could you tell me how to use this?

Comment: just use it as observable collection.when you call add method, it is going to check shared object(kinda thread safe).just create AsyncObservableCollection<ClassName> col = new AsyncObservableCollection<ClassName>(); then col.Add(item);

Comment: I'm trying this code, the error isn't returned but the UI is freeze, I don't why, maybe is the large amount of data. I'm going to try this with a thread or something like.

Comment: Maybe you should try to call it from a backgroundworker if your data is large or you dont want to wait it to finish.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying with a thread more or less is better but I think that in this case a BackGroundWorker should the right choice.